# React Table not loading from Network Request

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a table from my api. I did the following code:

```
export class News extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      dataObject: [],
      currentPage: 1,
      ItemsPerPage: 10,
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(event) {
    this.setState({
      currentPage: Number(event.target.id),
    });
  }

  getAll = () => {
    return new newsServices().GetNews().then((data) => {
      this.setState({ dataObject: data });
    });
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getAll();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Get the Latest BEE News</h1>

        <table>
          <tbody>
            {this.state.dataObject.map((result) => {
              return (
                <tr>
                  <td>{result.Subject}</td>
                  <td>{result.Summary}</td>
                  <td>{result.Url}</td>
                </tr>
              );
            })}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

But I am getting the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: this.state.dataObject.map is not a function`
My Json response looks as follows:

```
    [{"Id":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
"Date":"2019-05-06T00:00:00",
"Subject":"Barloworld optimistic ‘black public’ will take up offer to invest in new property group",
"Summary":"Industrial group Barloworld is optimistic that qualifying black South Africans will respond positively to its offer to buy a maximum of 30% of the shares available in a new black-owned property company, called Khula Sizwe Property Holdings, being created as part of a larger R3.5-billion broad-based black economic empowerment (BBBEE) transaction.",
"Url":"https://m.engineeringnews.co.za/article/barloworld-optimistic-black-public-will-take-up-offer-to-invest-in-new-property-group-2019-04-25",
"Active":true}
```

I need to get my table only to show the Data, Subject, Summary, and Url, which if i can get one to show then i should be able to get all of them to show but i have no idea why my code is not working

**UPDATE**
Here is my getNews Function:

```
    export class newsServices extends BaseApiService {
    GetNews() {
        return this.get(ApiUrls.NewsGetAll);
    }

//ApiUrls is 'News/GetAll'
```

My baseApiService:

```
    const axios = require('axios');

import { baseApiUrl } from '../constants/ApiUrls';

export class BaseApiService {
    get<T>(url: string) {
        return axios.get(`${baseApiUrl}${url}`).then((response: any) => {
            return {
                isSuccess: true,
                value: response.data as T,
                errorMessage: ''
            }
        }).catch((ex: any) => {
            return {
                isSuccess: false,
                value: {} as T,
                errorMessage: ex.message
            }
        });
    }

    post<T>(url: string, data: any) {
        return axios.post(`${baseApiUrl}${url}`, data).then((response: any) => {
            return {
                isSuccess: true,
                value: response.data as T,
                errorMessage: ''
            }
        }).catch((ex: any) => {
            return {
                isSuccess: false,
                value: {} as T,
                errorMessage: ex.message
            }
        });
    }
}

}
```

Comment: are you sure, GetNews is always returning array?

Comment: @RahulSharma Yes, It will always Return an array

Comment: nothing wrong with your code :(

Comment: console log this.state.dataObject and tell us whats the result

Comment: return new newsServices().GetNews().then((data) => {
      console.log(typeof data);
       this.setState({ dataObject: data });
    });

check this

Comment: @FarhanHaque That console logs object

Comment: @Roy.B An Empty object, but looking at the network tab my request was made and data was received

Comment: can you share the code of GetNews function

Comment: @MohammedIsmail well that's your problem, you don't pass the response and obviously, you cannot map on object

Comment: @RahulSharma I updated the question with requested code

Comment: I think it should be `this.setState({ dataObject: data.value });`

Comment: Rahul looks to be correct - you return an object from you api Promise, that has a value property which is your actual json array response.

Comment: @RahulSharma , its still giving me this error in console `Uncaught TypeError: this.state.dataObject.map is not a function`

Comment: @RahulSharma I didn't mean to steal your answer, just wanted to make sure if got answered. Please add an answer yourself (take my content if you like) and I will delete mine.

Comment: @DavidHall NP David, I was about to tell Mohammed to add an answer also. If it's working so that others can refer to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `get` method of your `baseApiService` returns an object and not an array.

```
get<T>(url: string) {
    return axios.get(`${baseApiUrl}${url}`).then((response: any) => {
        return {
            isSuccess: true,
            value: response.data as T,
            errorMessage: ''
        }
    }).catch((ex: any) => {
        return {
            isSuccess: false,
            value: {} as T,
            errorMessage: ex.message
        }
    });
}
```

So in your code when you assign the response from `GetNews` to your state's `dataObject` property, you have something like this...

```
this.state.dataObject = {
            isSuccess: true,
            value: [your data]
            errorMessage: ''
        }
```

Which you can't call map on, since it is not an array.

To fix the problem, either return that data array assigned to `value` from `GetNews`, or reference `this.state.dataObject.value` when you access your state, or assign your value property into the dataObject `this.setState({ dataObject: data.value })`